# Create and show thumbnails

Tags: php, image

I am calling `show_thumb` to create thumbnails , but I am realizing that it is making the site load a little bit slower.

Below are two functions: `show_thumb` function that shows the thumbnail and `make_thumb_gd` that takes care of the thumbnail. Any suggestion on making it faster? The current approach makes the site slow, because those thumbnails are shown in the moving `Jcarousel` that contains the links returned by `show_thumb`.

Show thumb function

```
function show_thumb($file_org, $width, $height,$folder_version,$ratio_type = 'width')
{

    $file_name = str_replace(SITE_WS_PATH."/", "", $file_org);
    $file_name = str_replace("/", "^", $file_name);
    $file_name = preg_replace("/[ ]+/", "_", $file_name);
    $cache_file = $width."x".$height.'__'.$ratio_type .'__'.$file_name;
    $folder_version = trim($folder_version); 

    if($folder_version =="english"){

        $version ="";
    }
    else {

        $version = $folder_version;
    }

    $file_fs_path = str_replace(SITE_WS_PATH, ROOT, $file_org); 

    if(!is_file(ROOT."/".$version."/".THUMB_CACHE_DIR."/".$cache_file)) {

       $d = make_thumb_gd($file_fs_path, ROOT."/".$version."/".THUMB_CACHE_DIR."/".$cache_file, $width, $height, $ratio_type );



    }else{
        @unlink(ROOT."/".$version."/".THUMB_CACHE_DIR."/".$cache_file);
        make_thumb_gd_1($file_fs_path, ROOT."/".$version."/".THUMB_CACHE_DIR."/".$cache_file, $width, $height, $ratio_type );
    }

    if($folder_version =="english"){

        $link = SITE_WS_PATH."/".THUMB_CACHE_DIR."/".$cache_file;
    }
    else {

        $link = SITE_WS_PATH."/".$folder_version."/".THUMB_CACHE_DIR."/".$cache_file;
    }   

    return $link;
}
```

Make thumb function

```
function make_thumb_gd($imgPath, $destPath, $newWidth, $newHeight, $ratio_type = 'width', $quality = 60, $verbose = false)
{ 
    // options for ratio type = width|height|distort|crop
    // get image info (0 width and 1 height, 2 is (1 = GIF, 2 = JPG, 3 = PNG)
    $size = @getimagesize($imgPath); 
    // break and return false if failed to read image infos
    if (!$size) {
        if ($verbose) {
            echo "Unable to read image info.";
        }
        return false;
    } 
    $curWidth   = $size[0];
    $curHeight  = $size[1];
    $fileType   = $size[2];

    // width/height ratio
    $ratio =  $curWidth/$curHeight;

    $srcX = 0;
    $srcY = 0;
    $srcWidth = $curWidth;
    $srcHeight = $curHeight;

    if($ratio_type=='width') {
        // If the dimensions for thumbnails are greater than original image do not enlarge
        if($newWidth > $curWidth) {
            $newWidth = $curWidth;
        }
        $newHeight  = $newWidth / $ratio;
    }else if($ratio_type=='crop') {
        $thumbRatio = $newWidth / $newHeight;
        if($ratio < $thumbRatio) {
            $srcHeight = round($curHeight*$ratio/$thumbRatio);
            $srcY = round(($curHeight-$srcHeight)/2);
        } else {
            $srcWidth = round($curWidth*$thumbRatio/$ratio);
            $srcX = round(($curWidth-$srcWidth)/2);
        }
        /*echo "<br>curWidth: $curWidth";
        echo "<br>curHeight: $curHeight";
        echo "<br>newWidth: $newWidth";
        echo "<br>newHeight: $newHeight";
        echo "<br>ratio: $ratio";
        echo "<br>thumbRatio: $thumbRatio";
        echo "<br>srcWidth: $srcWidth";
        echo "<br>srcX: $srcX";
        echo "<br>srcHeight: $srcHeight";
        echo "<br>srcY: $srcY";*/
    } else if($ratio_type=='height') {
        // If the dimensions for thumbnails are greater than original image do not enlarge
        if($newHeight > $curHeight) {
            $newHeight = $curHeight;
        }
        $newWidth   = $newHeight * $ratio;
    } else if($ratio_type=='distort') {
    }

    // create image
    switch ($fileType) {
        case 1:
            if (function_exists("imagecreatefromgif")) {
                $originalImage = imagecreatefromgif($imgPath);
            } else {
                if ($verbose) {
                    echo "GIF images are not support in this php installation.";
                    return false;
                }
            } 
            $fileExt = 'gif';
            break;
        case 2: 
            $originalImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgPath);
            $fileExt = 'jpg';
            break;
        case 3: 
            $quality = 9;
            $originalImage = imagecreatefrompng($imgPath);
            $fileExt = 'png';
            break;
        default:
            if ($verbose) {
                echo "Not a valid image type.";
            }
            return false;
    } 
    // create new image

    $resizedImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
    //echo "$srcX, $srcY, $newWidth, $newHeight, $curWidth, $curHeight";
    //echo "<br>$srcX, $srcY, $newWidth, $newHeight, $srcWidth, $srcHeight<br>";
    imagecopyresampled($resizedImage, $originalImage, 0, 0, $srcX, $srcY, $newWidth, $newHeight, $srcWidth, $srcHeight);
    switch ($fileExt) {
        case 'gif':
            imagegif($resizedImage, $destPath, $quality);
            break;
        case 'jpg': 
            imagejpeg($resizedImage, $destPath, $quality);
            break;
        case 'png':
            $quality = 9;
            imagepng($resizedImage, $destPath, $quality);
            break;
    } 
    // return true if successfull
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Well unlike most PHP functionality, image processing is processor intensive rather than RAM intensive. So a lower grade processor could be a factor. Beyond that, make this script faster is no different than optimizing other PHP scripts; just prevent redundant actions and free any resources as soon as you can.

Comment: So is there anything I can improve on the script or is it written just fine ?

Comment: @StevieNix I am not gonna sit here and do your job for you. You want your code faster, look for ways to make it faster, and then *you* apply them. If you want tips that can generally make your code faster then your in the right place. For example, I can tell you that the `@` silencer will always slow your application down. I can also tell you, that if your using `@` you have made your code wrong, and need to back and fix it so that no `@`s are required.

Comment: Only call `make_thumb_gd` when absolutely required. If the thumbnail has already been generated and cached then you don't need to regenerate it. No need to `unlink` and recreate the work that has already been done, assuming the image hasn't changed since it's last thumbnail generation.

Comment: @MrYellow .. THANK YOU !!  make_thumb_gd was called each time the images are displayed , that's why the site it slow .. I should only use it when uploading images , then if they exist , just provide the link to it stored in the database

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks nice, but it could be improved in places:

---

### **`show_thumb()`**:

1. Whitespace is missing in many places, and should be added in between operators, or between commas.

> ```
> $height,$folder_version,$ratio_type = 'width'
> $cache_file = $width."x".$height.'__'.$ratio_type .'__'.$file_name;
> if(!is_file(ROOT."/".$version."/".THUMB_CACHE_DIR."/".$cache_file)) {
> ```

2. The method you use to run over the `$folder_version` feels really backwards and should be changed.

   ```
   if($folder_version != "english"){
       $version = $folder_version;
   } else {
       $version = "";
   }
   ```

That is much clearer, however if you're into ternaries, you could use the following to shorten it:

```
$version = ($folder_version == "english" ? "" : $folder_version);
```

3. You shouldn't build a long string instead an if statement like the following as it is bad practice.

> ```
> if(!is_file(ROOT."/".$version."/".THUMB_CACHE_DIR."/".$cache_file)) {
>    $d = make_thumb_gd($file_fs_path, ROOT."/".$version."/".THUMB_CACHE_DIR."/".$cache_file, $width, $height, $ratio_type );
> }else{
>     @unlink(ROOT."/".$version."/".THUMB_CACHE_DIR."/".$cache_file);
>     make_thumb_gd_1($file_fs_path, ROOT."/".$version."/".THUMB_CACHE_DIR."/".$cache_file, $width, $height, $ratio_type );
> }
> ```

Instead, you should:

```
$url = ROOT . "/$version/". THUMB_CACHE_DIR . "/$cache_file";
if(!is_file($url)){
   $d = make_thumb_gd($file_fs_path, $url, $width, $height, $ratio_type);
} else {
    @unlink($url);
    make_thumb_gd_1($file_fs_path, $url, $width, $height, $ratio_type);
}
```

4. Is `make_thumb_gd_1()` really a thing, or did you misspell? (*Why use two seperate functions?*)
5. The following code seems again, backwards, and could be shortened with some refactoring, or a ternary. I'd suggest the latter.

> ```
> if($folder_version =="english"){
>
>    $link = SITE_WS_PATH."/".THUMB_CACHE_DIR."/".$cache_file;
> }
> else {
>
>    $link = SITE_WS_PATH."/".$folder_version."/".THUMB_CACHE_DIR."/".$cache_file;
> }   
>
> return $link;
> ```

into:

```
return = SITE_WS_PATH . "/" . ($version == "english" ? "" : $version) . THUMB_CACHE_DIR . "/$cache_file";
```

---

### **`make_thumb_gd()`**:

The code in this function seems a lot better formatted, and even has comments!

1. You space the operator out here, so that it's formatted better, but they can be brought in another space:

> ```
> $curWidth   = $size[0];
> $curHeight  = $size[1];
> $fileType   = $size[2];
> ```

into:

```
$curWidth  = $size[0];
$curHeight = $size[1];
$fileType  = $size[2];
```

2. you shouldn't skip a few characters at the expense of readability:
   Instead of `cur`, use `current` (*assuming that's what the abbreviation is for*)
3. You should add whitespace around your operators to improve readability:

> ```
> round(($curWidth-$srcWidth)/2);
> ```

4. Your comment openers/closers (`/*`, `*/`) should always be on a different line than the comment content. Also, misspell.

> ```
> // return true if successfull
>                             ^
> ```